# superfish horizontal nav bar not getting displayed in the page

Tags: layout, css

I coded horizontal nav with superfish. It working fine when not added to my page. When added to my page its not getting displayed. [my page](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/mock2.html) here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/zJxR3/) for navigation
demo nav

Comment: It's pretty sad that I recognize that page enough to know that you have another account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/629305/dragonfly

Comment: You're probably getting hit with the "consistent low quality questions" stick. See here for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `position: relative` from `#wrapper`.

Alternatively, you can add `z-index: 1` to `#chromemenu`.

You should read this to understand `z-index`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index

Comment: @thirtydot -- i removed position: relative and z-index: 5. still nav bar is not visible

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you changed, but that live page still has `position: relative` on `#wrapper`. Remove it. It's line 299 in `content2.css`.

Comment: Ok, you're still changing stuff. Add `position: relative` to `#chromemenu` and it's fixed (unless you go and change it again)..

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking me.

Comment: @thirtydot -- i asked you y did we change #wrapper position:relative. How did it fixed it. I changed since you said it would work. but I want i want to know how it solved the issue

Comment: As I said, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index - specifically, having `position: relative` on `#wrapper`, but not on `#chromemenu` meant that `#wrapper` was being shown *on top of* `#chromemenu`. The menu was always there, but just hidden underneath `#wrapper`. Does that make sense?